# Is there a way to match pixels in figma and Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, figma

I create a UI design using figma and then create a screen using Flutter, but since each pixel in figma is different from each pixel in Flutter, it takes a lot of time.
How can I create something without being aware of the differences in pixels between Figma and Flutter?

Comment: You can check the screenutil package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil
You can set the size of the screen to match your figma design